# Problema em busca SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou fazendo um exercício onde, para cada nome de uma disciplina, preciso retornar a quantidade de alunos aprovados e reprovados.
Quando faço a busca dos alunos aprovados e reprovados, de forma separada, eu consigo o resultado esperado:

```
SELECT D.nome, COUNT (H2.conceito) as reprovado
FROM disciplina D , historico H2
WHERE D.nome = 'Calculo'  and H2.conceito ='reprovado'
GROUP BY D.nome, H2.conceito

SELECT D.nome, COUNT (H.conceito) as aprovado
FROM disciplina D , historico H
WHERE D.nome = 'Calculo' and H.conceito = 'aprovado'
GROUP BY D.nome, H.conceito
```

O resultado correto seria 2 alunos aprovados e 2 reprovados, porém quando junto os códigos para fazer a busca junta, o resultado sai como 4 alunos aprovados e 4 reprovados

```
SELECT D.nome, COUNT (H.conceito) as aprovado, COUNT (H2.conceito) as reprovado
FROM disciplina D , historico H, historico H2
WHERE D.nome = 'Calculo' and H.conceito = 'aprovado' and H2.conceito ='reprovado'
GROUP BY D.nome, H.conceito, H2.conceito
```

Tentei utilizar conceito como DISTINCT, porém não funcionou também.

Comment: Qual a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas? Pode editar a pergunta e incluir os creates das tabelas e alguns insert para que possamos simular? A princípio posso adiantar que quando possue duas tabelas, precisa fazer `join` para unir as tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: Isso está ocorrendo porque você está agrupando seus dados. Tenta fazer usando CASE WHEN.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer esse controle é, ao invés de dois *joins* com a tabela de *histórico*, trazer o controle de aprovado/reprovado do `where`, somando ([`sum`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sum-function/)) de acordo com o *conceito* - controle feito via [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-conditional.html).

```
SELECT D.nome,
       SUM(CASE WHEN H.conceito = 'aprovado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as aprovado, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN H.conceito = 'reprovado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reprovado
FROM disciplina D , historico H
WHERE D.nome = 'calculo'
GROUP BY D.nome
```

Criei um [snipet com um teste](https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/945ffdb) de exemplo

Comment: dê uma olhada na complementação do seu exemplo e no resultado da execução. Veja se precisa fazer algum ajuste na sua resposta. Tudo de bom pra vc. Exemplo complementado: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b47f02/1

Answer (score -1):

Nessa solução busquei oferecer 3 opções de resolução, sendo elas:

- Solução Proposta 01 - Com GROUP BY
- Solução Proposta 02 - Com SubConsulta
- Solução Proposta 03 - Com CASE WHEN

As soluções foram testadas no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b47f02/45). Utilizei como base inicial o modelo de dados fornecido pelo @rLinhares na resposta dele com pequenos ajustes.
No final da resposta, mostrarei o problema de incluir mais de uma tabela após o `from` e não realizar a junção `join` ficando assim exemplificado na `Query PROBLEMA` com a explicação logo após a demonstração do resultado desta `query`.

### Solução Proposta 01 - Com GROUP BY

Visto que na pergunta está constando o uso da cláusula `GROUP BY` conforme citação abaixo:

> ```
> SELECT D.nome, COUNT (H.conceito) as aprovado, COUNT (H2.conceito) as reprovado
> FROM disciplina D , historico H, historico H2
> WHERE D.nome = 'Calculo' and H.conceito = 'aprovado' and H2.conceito ='reprovado'
> GROUP BY D.nome, H.conceito, H2.conceito`
> ```

Apresento a possibilidade de solução seguinte:

```
-- Solução Proposta 01 - Com GROUP BY
SELECT d.nome, h.conceito, Count(*) as Quantidade
  FROM disciplina d
  Left join historico h on d.id_disciplina = h.id_disciplina
  WHERE d.nome = 'calculo'
  group by d.id_disciplina, h.conceito, d.nome
  order by d.id_disciplina, h.conceito, d.nome
```

**Resultado:**

```
|    nome |  conceito | quantidade |
|---------|-----------|------------|
| calculo |  aprovado |          2 |
| calculo | reprovado |          3 |
```

### Solução Proposta 02 - Com SubConsulta

Esta solução também pode ser utilizada para solucionar, apesar de não ser muito utilizada para essa finalidade.

```
-- Solução Proposta 02 - Com SubConsulta
SELECT d.Nome,
       (Select count(*) from historico h where h.id_disciplina = d.id_disciplina and h.conceito = 'aprovado') as aprovado, 
       (Select count(*) from historico h where h.id_disciplina = d.id_disciplina and h.conceito = 'reprovado') as reprovado 
  FROM disciplina d
 WHERE d.nome = 'calculo'
```

**Resultado:**

```
|    nome | aprovado | reprovado |
|---------|----------|-----------|
| calculo |        2 |         3 |
```

### Solução Proposta 03 - Com CASE WHEN

Como está usando o `SUM`, é necessário também do `group by`.

```
-- Solução Proposta 03 - Com CASE WHEN
SELECT d.nome, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN H.conceito = 'aprovado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as aprovado, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN H.conceito = 'reprovado' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as reprovado
  FROM disciplina d 
  Left join historico h on d.id_disciplina = h.id_disciplina
 WHERE d.nome = 'calculo' 
 group by d.nome
```

**Resultado**:

```
|    nome | aprovado | reprovado |
|---------|----------|-----------|
| calculo |        2 |         3 |
```

### O Problema que ocorre se não usar o `join` corretamente

**Query PROBLEMA**:

```
-- Caso sem o join
SELECT D.nome, COUNT (H.conceito) as aprovado, COUNT (H2.conceito) as reprovado
  FROM disciplina D , historico H, historico H2
 WHERE D.nome = 'calculo' and H.conceito = 'aprovado' and H2.conceito ='reprovado'
GROUP BY D.nome, H.conceito, H2.conceito
```

**Resultado**:

```
|    nome | aprovado | reprovado |
|---------|----------|-----------|
| calculo |       12 |        12 |
```

Nessa situação acima, se não utilizar a **JUNÇÃO** será realizada um álgebra relacional de todos os registros que satisfaçam a cláusula WHERE.

- disciplinas com nome = 'calculo': 1 Registro
- `H.conceito = 'aprovado'`: 4 Registros
- `H2.conceito ='reprovado'`: 3 Registros
  Multiplica tudo, pois não tem o `join`: 1 x 4 x 3 = 12 registros